# Finding an replacing string matches in lists Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I volunteer for a modded minecraft community as a Moderators, and we deal with chatlogs frequently.
I'm building a program to take a server's chatlog, find matching usernames in it and writing them to a new file.
The way I have it at the moment, it takes the file, and converts each line into a list item, I regex the username using an expression, and write the line if it contains a match. The problem is, the way chatlogs come they are formatted like this: `BOTusername`, and I want to use the program to strip the `BOT` part before searching (makes it neater when written at the end.)

I know this is possible when you read the file normally using `f.read('file.txt')` but I was wondering if its possible do this with a list instead. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Column01/2199d704e7954a856817b0c37d0e178a) is an example of what the list looks like.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
import os
import re
username = 'UsernameHere'
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open('chatlogs.txt', 'r') as f:
    chatlogs = f.readlines()
print(chatlogs) # for debugging

# Checks the chatlogs for username matches
for line in chatlogs:
    if re.match('(.*)' + username + '(.*)', line):
        d = open('output.txt', 'a')
        d.write(line)
```

Comment: If you're certain that your lines will start like `BOTusername` you could start writing from the 3rd letter.   `d.write(line[3:])`

Comment: That is not viable since the timestamp will not always be the same length (4 or 3 characters). See the comment on the answer below for an example of what a message looks like

Comment: You could split your line at the first `']'`, discard the timestamp and then print from the 3rd spot in the line. Something like `d.write(line.split(']',1)[1][3:])` where the `,1` tells you to only split once and the `[1]` will give you the part of that string that was after the `']'` and of course the `[3:]` will start printing at character 3

Comment: Problem is the timestamps are important for moderation reasons. Is there a way to save the timestamp in this process? I'm not familiar with `split` or how it works but based on this example, it splits the timestamp off from the rest of the list item into its own item so in theory it could be preserved and written to the file?

Comment: Yep, you can save both parts.  You'll have to do the `split()` outside of your print statement though.  Something like `timestamp, text = line.split(']',1)` then you can just write from the `text` string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `username` variable consistently looks like "BOTsomeusername", you can strip the first three characters with some simple indexing:

```
username = username[3:]
```

Comment: The username is not on its own, it also includes the timestamp, the server it was sent to and the message itself. Here is an example of what a message looks like `[11:32 AM] BOTVeraz (Enigmatica) it depends on how much your feeding it'` meaning writing from a specific character onward (as commented on the original post) will not work as the amount of characters it includes before the actual username starts will change depending on the timestamp of the message. One potential fix for that is making the chat logs use 24h timestamps instead of standard time, but this is not ideal

Comment: The username variable will be filled by the user wanting to filter chat messages for that username

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hoog for pointing me in the right direction!

I got it to work with the following code:

```
for line in chatlogs:
    if re.match('(.*)' + username + '(.*)', line):
        d = open('output.txt', 'a')
        timestamp = line.split(']', 1)[0] + '] ' # includes the bracket that gets removed in the split operation
        message = line.split('] ', 1)[1][3:] # saves the remainder of the message after the third character (After BOT)
        d.write(timestamp + message)
```